# How to store return value of function into a variable and subsequently use it in while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, while-loop

Hi I'm literally new to python and programming in general ---- **a complete beginner**. I'm 2 hours in in some youtube python beginner course and he made some guessing game to demonstrate the application of a while loop.

I replicated it so I can practice coding but I made some modifications to it on my own.

He made the guessing game where you can have 3 tries to guess the word using a combination of while loop, if and else functions, and Boolean variable.

**My version** is similar but I wanted it to have a counter where you are informed of how many tries you have left.

```
secret_word = "Aircraft"
answer = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
remaining_guess = guess_limit - guess_count

while answer != secret_word and remaining_guess != 0:
    if guess_count < guess_limit and remaining_guess == 3:

        def re_guesses(remaining_guess_1):
            print("You have " + str(remaining_guess_1) + " remaining guesses")
            int(remaining_guess_1)
            return remaining_guess_1
        remaining_guess = re_guesses(remaining_guess)

        def guess_word(guess_count_1):

                answer = input("Enter answer: ")
                guess_count_1 += 1
                return guess_count_1

        guess_count = guess_word(guess_count)

    elif guess_count < guess_limit and remaining_guess == 2:

        def re_guesses(remaining_guess_1):
            print("You have " + str(remaining_guess_1) + " remaining guesses")
            int(remaining_guess_1)
            return remaining_guess_1

        remaining_guess = re_guesses(remaining_guess)

        def guess_word(guess_count_1):

            answer = input("Enter answer: ")
            guess_count_1 += 1
            return guess_count_1

        guess_count = guess_word(guess_count)

    else:
        def re_guesses(remaining_guess_1):
            print("You have " + str(remaining_guess_1) + " remaining guesses")
            int(remaining_guess_1)
            return remaining_guess_1

        remaining_guess = re_guesses(remaining_guess)

        def guess_word(guess_count_1):

            answer = input("Enter answer: ")
            guess_count_1 += 1
            return guess_count_1

        guess_count = guess_word(guess_count)



if remaining_guess == 0:
    print("You lost!!")
else:
    print("I can't believe you won!")
```

I tried to store the return value (remaining_guess_1) again to the remaining_guess as I converted into an integer. I did the same to the return value of guess_count_1 and stored it in the orginal variable of guess_count.

I was expecting the result to be that the counter will subtract 1 try after every wrong answer but instead it is stuck to ***"You have 3 remaining guesses"***.

Please someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: You never decrement `remaining_guess` inside the loop.

Comment: because you never update the value of `remaining_guess`. it starts out an an int, you pass it as an arg to `re_guesses` and convert it to `int` (which it already is) and then return that value and re-assign it to `remaining_guess`, but the actual numeric value never changes

Comment: Yes. I see it now. Thank you. I just thought that it will decrement because I incremented the value of the `guess_count` by 1, which in turn should decrement the `remaining guess` basing off of the variable I made. But clearly it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and found some ways to simplify the while loop process so that you don't have all of those "if/else" blocks.  Moving around the definitions and the "while" loop, I came up with the following code.

```
secret_word = "Aircraft"
answer = ""
guess_limit = 3
remaining_guesses = guess_limit

def re_guesses(remaining_guess_1):
    print("You have " + str(remaining_guess_1) + " remaining guesses")
    int(remaining_guess_1)

def guess_word():
    answer = input("Enter answer: ")
    return answer
    
re_guesses(remaining_guesses)

while remaining_guesses != 0:
    answer = guess_word()
    if (answer == secret_word):
        break
    else:
        print(answer, ' was not the correct answer')
        remaining_guesses -= 1
        re_guesses(remaining_guesses)

if remaining_guesses == 0:
    print("You lost!!")
else:
    print("I can't believe you won!")
```

The function definitions and the initial prompt are moved before the while loop is called.  Also, instead of returning the guess count, I revised the "guess_word" function to return the entered answer.  Then based on the correctness (or incorrectness) of the answer, the loop is exited with a "break" call if the answer was correct, or the remaining guess count gets decremented if incorrect.  If the user answers correctly before the remaining count hits zero, they are notified that they won.  Also, I didn't see a use anymore for the guess count so I removed that variable both from the variable list and from the input parameter for the "guess_word" function.

Go ahead and study the code and see if it meets your needs and provides you with some ideas.

Regards.

Comment: hello! Thank you for your help! this code is much better --- less clutter. It just goes to show how much of a noob I am lol.

I just have to ask regarding the functions. Why is all of the guess_word function not inside the loop? why is it only the function call? Would it work the same way if all of it was inside the loop?

And for the else statement, why is the function call of the re_guesses in there when you already called it earlier? is it to update the remaining guesses since you decremented it? Would it not decrement if you didn't put that function call of re_guesses?

Comment: You could probably fashion the guess function in such a way to have it inside a loop.  Usually, there are at least two or three good ways to handle loops.  The main takeaway is to be able to break out of the loop if and when a user correctly guesses.  Also, if you decide upon a specific method for setting up loops with possible exit points, it is best to be consistent in how you test (and if need be, how you exit).  I found the single best thing to do when coding is be as consistent in your coding practices.  That helped me a lot.  Regards.